# Not able to ssh/http into EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-security-group

I am at my wits end with this, please help.

I am creating EC2 instances in my default public VPC, yet i am not able to ssh or http to my instance or webserver running into the machine. I checked the following

- The SG has inbound SSH, HTTP and HTTPS allowed from 0.0.0.0/0 and assigned to my instance
- the default VPC, has route tables with 0.0.0.0/0 pointed to IGW
- the NACLs are configured to Allow all traffic. i also manually updated to allow only HHTP, HTTPS and SSH
- the Key is use has been given the right permission by running *chmod 400 filename*

Despite all this not able to connect to the EC2 instance, AMI being Amazon Linux 2 AMI

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I try to ssh, i get a connection timeout error after a while, initially, i thought it was my office network but I am also getting the same from my home network with no firewalls in place

Comment: Does your SG egress allow outgoing connections?

Comment: yes, initially it allowed all traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 now i have also updated to SSH, HTTP and HTTPS just to check and same problem persists. updated with iamges

Comment: Please could you share the command you are trying to use to connect?

Comment: can you telnet to the port <22> ? can you share the ssh verbose logs? there are 6 outbound rules configured in the security picture you shared.. can you check those ?

Comment: @AugustWilliams its the standard command from connect , ssh -i "privatepair.pem" ec2-user@dnsname. i have also tried the public ip instead of dns still problem

Comment: @samtoddler i am using mac, i tried nc but even that is timing out

Comment: @Tatha did you checked those 6 outbound rules in the SG. If you are not able to ssh then it is totally a networking problem. In the comment you mention you are using <dnsname>, is it possible you can try using the public IP address of the instance?
One more thing I would is to check the ssh connection or telnet from someone else's machine too , just rule out any trouble on your machine.

Comment: What are the outbound NACLs rules? Usually you leave NACLs in their default state, without modifying them.

Comment: @samtoddler i tried with both dnsname and public ip and also from my office laptop connected to office network and also personal laptop with home network same issue, though separate instances as i needed separate ssh keys

Comment: Please show us debug output by using `ssh -vvv -i "privatepair.pem" ec2-user@dnsname`. Do you have any other instances in the same subnet that work correctly?

Comment: Also, be aware of the new [VPC Reachability Analyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/how-reachability-analyzer-works.html).

Comment: @jarmod thanks for your inputs , but once i reverted back to default NACL rules it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow an SSH connection, you will need:

- An Amazon EC2 instance running **Linux** launched in a **public subnet** (defined as having a Route Table that directs `0.0.0.0/0` to an Internet Gateway)
- A **Security Group** permitting Inbound access on port 22 (Outbound configuration is irrelevant)
- **Network ACLs** left at their default settings of Allow All in **both directions**
- A **Public IP address** associated with the instance

From your descriptions, I would say that the problem is probably with the **Outbound NACLs**. Return traffic from an SSH session goes back to the source port on the initiating server, which is *not* port 22. In general, only change the NACLs if you have a specific reason, such as creating a DMZ. I recommend you reset the NACL rules to Allow All traffic in both directions.

Comment: Thanks @John , once i reverted back to default NACL settings which is allow all traffice from 0.0.0.0/0 i was able to ssh into the instance. I was not sure why allowing only ssh, http,https shouldnt do it but TIL that ssh ports fr the caller may be different than 22 and that makes sense. thanks for your help

Comment: Correct. When establishing an SSH connection, the traffic goes _to_ port 22, but it comes from a different port. That's how one computer can establish multiple SSH connections -- each comes from different source port (to which the return traffic is sent) that the traffic doesn't get mixed together.